# Why is ogrinfo showing no layers from an ESRI FileGDB?

Tags: postgresql, esri-geodatabase, ogr, ogr2ogr, file-geodatabase

I have an ESRI File Geodatabase (FileGDB) (size is 15+GB), which has over 10 layers, when I open it up in ArcGIS, everything seems to be working.

I want to move this database to postgreSQL with OGR `ogr2ogr`.

First I am checking the `ogrinfo` with:

```
ogrinfo pathToFileGDB
```

I get result:

```
INFO: Open of `C:\Foo\My Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb'
  using driver `FileGDB' successful.
```

But I see no layers, nor does the `ogr2ogr` see any layers. I should see all the layers here like I saw in ArcGIS. So I am unable to move it to postgreSQL.

I tested the same thing on a smaller `FileGDB`(800MB) and I can see all the layers with `ogrinfo`, also the `ogr2ogr` works.

What could be the problem? Is my DB too big, if so, what could be a workaround?
Any other suggestions?

Comment: I have the same problem, did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You could try passing `-al -so` to `ogrinfo`, e.g. 
`ogrinfo -al -so  pathToFileGDB`

Answer (score 1):

The file geodatabase must be a 10.0 version or newer for OGR. You can display the geodatabase version with arcpy.
print arcpy.Describe('c:/pathto/your.gdb').release
2,2,0 is  9.2
2,3,0 is  9.3.x
3,0,0 is  10.x

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is that the projection may not be recognized by the file gdb api - layers with "custom" projections may not show up:

http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/4578

Using ESRI tools, you could check that the layers in the larger .gdb have the same projection definition as the layers in the smaller tested .gdb. Recognized projections are somewhere in the ArcGIS install folders.